# cannot access '$' before initialization error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to import a javascript file to another javascript file using jquery but I keep on running into the error  `$(document).ready(function () { ReferenceError: Cannot access '$' before initialization` my current code is attached below. I included the `$.getScript` function inside `$(document).ready(function()) {` because I was trying to initialize jquery before $ assignment. Thanks in advance.

Current Code for trying to import js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //your code here
    $.getScript("index.js", function(){
        function time(){
            alert("the time is" + h)
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: The error implies that you’re using jQuery before you’ve imported the jQuery library.

Comment: How is this used on the page? Do you have a `<script>` tag to import jQuery? Do you use a packager?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica If that were the problem it would just say that `$` is undefined.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init

Comment: The error message implies that there's some code containing `let $;`

Comment: The problem isn't in the code that you posted. Maybe it's in `index.js`.